# How do I add image from Hashmap url to a listview item?

Tags: android, hashmap, imageview

In the followimg class, I have imported a thumb image using an hashmap, which is saved as a string. However, I wish to pass, via an intent, this image to a 
listview single item ie a detailed view. How do I add the s_thumb string to an
imageview in the detailed activity?
Here is the main activity, with the intent set out at the bottom:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {
    // All static variables
    static final String URL = "http://padihamcars.com/music.xml";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
    static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

    ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
        // looping through all song nodes <song>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
            map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
            map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
            map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
        }


        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
        adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);        
        list.setAdapter(adapter);


        // Click event for single list row
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {



                 HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    resultp   = songsList.get(position);
                    String s_thumb=resultp.get(KEY_THUMB_URL);
                    String s_title=resultp.get(KEY_TITLE);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(CustomizedListView.this, SingleListItem_Attractions.class);
                    intent.putExtra("s_id", s_thumb);
                    intent.putExtra("s_title", s_title);
                    //other fields you want to send
                    startActivity(intent);

            }
        });     
    }
```

And here is my detailed activity (single item):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SingleListItem_Attractions extends Activity{
    Button button;
    Button button2;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item_view);


        ImageView imageView = (InageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Intent i2 = getIntent();
        String text2 =i2.getStringExtra("s_thumb");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(text2);


        TextView texts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Intent i = getIntent();

        String text1 =i.getStringExtra("s_title");

        texts.setText(text1);

        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        final Context context = this;

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2); 
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, CustomizedListView.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        }





        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, CustomizedListView.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            }





            });                        

}
}
```

The problem lies with the ImageView trying to be set by a string ie text2.
What is the correct way to set the imageview from the url string in text2??
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have url of an image, you can use any of these `ImageLoaders` - [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the volley library have a look here https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

First in your gradle

```
dependencies {
...
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}
```

Then create a RequestQueue

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

Then create an ImageRequest

```
    ImageRequest request = new ImageRequest(yourUrl, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(response);
        }
    }, 0, 0, null, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {   
            Log.e(TAG, error.toString();
        }
    });
```

Add the request to the queue

```
    queue.add(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Universal Image Loader to set image to imageview from url. check this [Universal Image Loader](http://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Answer (score 0):

User Picasso Library :

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

and pass image url using intent and set image in imageview with Picasso library like belo code :

```
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party library for fast and reliable way of displaying images via url.

I recommend Glide:
https://github.com/bumptech/glide

In the link above you should be interested in sections **Download** and **How do I use Glide?** for including Glide in your project and using it.

All in all the final code for loading an image in your detailed activity (single item) should look something like this:

```
Glide
.with(getContext())
.load(text2)
.into(imageView);
```

Glide (as well as other image libraries) will provide you with many methods for customising your image (e. g. scaling, resizing). Refer to docs.